# create user with procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I try to create a user account mysql with a procedure but is not working
the problem is the procedure is not call the variable username
you have an idea please

```
CREATE PROCEDURE databaseA.Test(username varchar(255))
CREATE USER username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
```

> CALL TEST("Admin2")

MySQL a répondu: Documentation

## 1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'username'@'localhost'

Comment: When You are using this procedure?

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos Trzos in phpmyAdmin the error is CALL TEST("Admin2")

MySQL a répondu: Documentation
#1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'username'@'localhost'

Comment: I don't know if You can create users in that way. It's returning error, because You have created "username" user earlier with that procedure. It's getting user name from name of the variable. If You will change `username` on `xxx` (for example), it would create user `xxx@localhost`.

Comment: I really don't know why it's behaving like this...

Answer (score 1):

my solution to this problem, I hope that will help you :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DatabaseA.Test(IN username varchar(100), IN pwd varchar(255))
  BEGIN
    SET @createUserCMD = concat('CREATE USER ''', username, '''@''', 'localhost', '''IDENTIFIED BY ''', pwd, ''';');
    PREPARE createUserStatement FROM @createUserCMD;
    EXECUTE createUserStatement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE createUserStatement;   
  END//
```